# How to correctly link an opengl program under debian?

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glfw, glew

To learn how to do opengl, I have a minimalist build system and a toy program. My makefile produces these commands:

```
g++ -O1 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++   main.o  -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL -o main
```

In that directory I have a lone main.cpp file. Contrary to many questions here on SO, this actually works. **It compiles and links without problems**. However, when I run the program, **it merely displays the background colour I write with `glClear` but not my test triangle**.

I have verified that it's not a problem with my code, because if I compile it with a (quite complex and bloated) build system I found in a tutorial it seems to work. However, I want to *understand* how to actually build an opengl program myself. I suspect I am missing some library or something, but I would expect the program to crash, not to just do (almost) nothing.

I am running the newest debian.

**How can it be that it compiles and links perfectly, but fails to run correctly?**

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am absolutely new to opengl and windowed applications. I am not a 100% certain why I need glew.</sub>

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

bool install_shader(GLuint where, std::string const& code, GLuint* attach_to) {
  GLuint shader_id = glCreateShader(where);
  {
    auto const p = code.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader_id,1,&p,nullptr); // nullptr indicates null-termination here
  }
  glCompileShader(shader_id);
  GLint out;
  glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &out);
  if (out == GL_FALSE) {
    // something went wrong with the shader compilation
    glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &out);
    if (out == 0) {
      std::cout << "Unknown Error during shader compilation\n";
    } else {
      std::string error;
      error.resize(out-1);
      glGetShaderInfoLog(shader_id, out, nullptr, error.data());
      std::cout << "Shader Compilation failed with error: " << error;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    std::cout << "shader(" << int(shader_id) << "@" << int(where) << ") compiled fine\n";

    if (attach_to) {
      glAttachShader(*attach_to, shader_id);
    }

    // XXX THE SHADERS SHOULD BE DELETED AFTER LINKING !!!!
    // glDeleteShader(shader_id)

    return true;
  }
}

bool install_program(GLuint program_id) {
  glLinkProgram(program_id);
  GLint out;
  glGetProgramiv(program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &out);
  if (out == GL_FALSE) {
    // something went wrong with the program linking
    glGetProgramiv(program_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &out);
    if (out == 0) {
      std::cout << "Unknown link-Error in shader program\n";
    } else {
      std::string error;
      error.resize(out-1);
      glGetProgramInfoLog(program_id, out, nullptr, error.data());
      std::cout << "Program linking failed with error: " << error;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    std::cout << "program(" << int(program_id) << ") compiled fine\n";
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  if (glfwInit()) {
    std::cout <<  "Initialisation fine\n";
  } else {
    std::cout <<  "Initialisation failed\n";
    return 1;
  }

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

  if (GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"testwindow",nullptr,nullptr)) {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() == GLEW_OK) {
      std::cout << "GLEW also fine\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "GLEW says nope!\n";
      goto die;
      return 2;
    }

    //std::cout << "Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below...\n";
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    /*business*/
    // (1) specify the triangle to draw
    // An array of 3 vectors which represents 3 vertices
    GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
       -0.4f, -0.8f, 0.f,
        0.4f, -0.8f, 0.f,
        0.0f,  0.8f, 0.f,
    };
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    GLuint program_id = glCreateProgram();

    // (3) vertex shader
    std::string vshader_code = "#version 330 core\n"
      "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
      "\n"
      "void main()\n"
      "{\n"
      "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
      "}\n";

    if (!install_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vshader_code,&program_id)) {
      goto die;
    }

    std::string fshader_code = "#version 330 core\n"
      "out vec3 color;\n"
      "\n"
      "void main()\n"
      "{\n"
      "    color = vec3(0.9,0.8,0.1);\n"
      "}\n";

    if (!install_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fshader_code,&program_id)) {
      goto die;
    }

    if (!install_program(program_id)) {
      goto die;
    }

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    do {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      glUseProgram(program_id);


      glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // this 0 also refes to 'layout (location = 0)' in the vertex shader

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,        // this refes to 'layout (location = 0)' in the vertex shader
        3,        // each vertex has 3 coordinates (2d data is also possible)
        GL_FLOAT, // coordinates are of type GLfloat (GL_FLOAT)
        GL_FALSE, // we don't need the input data to be nomalised,
        0, //&g_vertex_buffer_data[3] - &g_vertex_buffer_data[0], // stride
        nullptr        // offset ptr
      );

      // Draw the triangle !
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
      glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

      glfwSwapBuffers(window);

      glfwPollEvents();
    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

  } else {
    std::cout << "Could not create window\n";
  }

  die:
  glfwTerminate();
  std::cout <<  "Terminated\n";
}
```

Comment: `I have verified that it's not a problem with my code, because if I compile it with a (quite complex and bloated) build system I found in a tutorial it seems to work.` that does not necessarily mean that the code is correct. You, in fact, could have some undefined behavior taking place, and the other build system might have other compile options, or for some other reason result in a different memory layout which might result in the code to run "correctly" even so it is technically not valid.

Comment: And the code would be helpful to figure out why it does not crash and where to hook in some error checks to track down the problem.

Comment: @t.niese: I put my code in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZDy7bb9X). I copied most of it pretty much from examples in tutorials. Primarily from opengl-tutorial.org and learnopengl.com.

Comment: The build system I found uses a copy of glfw and glew which is compiled and linked against. However, I consider this to be quite ugly. I'd like to link against the library that my system already provides. It's there for a reason.

Comment: Just to rule one thing out: In both cases, you run the program on the same machine with the same GPU? Because technically the given OpenGL setup is not valid and should only show a triangle with Nvidia GPUs and their drivers.

Comment: Same hardware, same operating system, Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Comment: @t.niese: What about the given opengl setup is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), and bind that to store the states the are required to draw the triangle:

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// your remaining code
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
// ...
```

> The compatibility OpenGL profile makes VAO object 0 a default object. The core OpenGL profile makes VAO object 0 not an object at all. So if VAO 0 is bound in the core profile, you should not call any function that modifies VAO state. This includes binding the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` with glBindBuffer.

Depending on the profile and/or driver there can be an active default VAO which would result in the traingle to be rendered. But to have a standard complain setup you are required to create a VAO for the object you want to render.

This does not really explain why it works with the bundled GLFW and GLEW, but maybe one of them creates a default VAO to mimic the compatibility profile behavior or the on of the NVIDIA driver.

You can check if you are in core profile or compatibility profile using that code:

```
GLint prof;
glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &prof);
std::cout << (prof&GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT) << " " << (prof&GL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works. Now to understand VAOs for me. Do you have any idea why the tutorial code worked without the VAO?

Comment: @bitmask that's why you should never assume that the code is correct and not relevant ;)

Comment: Yes yes, I know. My bad :)

Comment: @bitmask Without taking a closer look at the setup of the build system you used, and use glfw, and glew version I can only guess, that the profile has a different default there.

Comment: @bitmask I added some lines of code that you could include in your project to check it the context created with that build system is running with compatibility profile.

Comment: It outputs `1 0`. I suppose "compatibility" is bad and "core" is good?

Comment: @bitmask it outputs `1 0` in the environment where it worked without the VAO? That's strange. Anyhow, I don't think it's worth the time to figure out why it worked there, if it works with the correct setup :D. Well "compatibility" profile allows you to use old legacy OpenGL code which might be required by some projects, but due to that, it might make the OpenGL context slower as the driver needs to support the legacy code. And with "core" you have to use the modern API which the driver - in theory - could optimize better.

Comment: Yes, thought as much. I agree that it's not worth worrying why an invalid program worked. UB is UB is UB. I *NOW* read in the doc that modern opengl requires the use of a VAO.